# Blackberry package-id of apk2bar generated package

Tags: android, blackberry, apk, code-signing, blackberry-10

We have a problem where we would like to distribute our blackberry app as a new application - rather than an upgrade and the Blackberry portal is saying that our current .bar file has the same package ID as another app.  The .bar file is created from an android app using apk2bar.

Looking at the package id in the .bar's manifest file it's obviously a generated hash, and in trying to figure out where it comes from I found this comment on twitter from @BlackBerryDev:

> The package name and code signing key are both used to create the package ID.

(Source: https://twitter.com/ruvcan/status/327129884629553153)

My question is, what exactly is the code signing key - is that the developer certificate, or is it based on the client-*.csj files in the keystore, or both or something else?

What I need to know is what's the easiest way to get a new package ID without changing the package id of the underlying Android app?

What I'd like to know is how the blackberry code signing works with a bit more detail.  I haven't been able to find a good explanation of how all the bits (client-RDK.csj, client-PBDT.csj, developer certificate, key store, blackberry ID, android package id, version numbers, portal packages, applications vs upgrades etc...) all tie together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .csj file is your code signing keys. These are what is used to create the package ID.

If you want a new Package ID, you should be able to request new keys, and use them to repackage your app.